# Plugin to show download only after the form has been fielded out?

Tags: forms

Is there a plugin that will only show the Download path after a form has been filled out eg: after the email address has been filled out and the user clicks on submit the download url will be returned?

Answer (score 1):

[Link Vault](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/link-vault) is a good one.

Alternatively you could always display the link on the forms result page and utilise [Freeform](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freeform) to control validation of the results page and saving of the form data.